# xml2 namespace / xpath issue when converting to dataframe

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I am trying to convert an xml document to a flat dataframe using `xml2`.

Here's some sample code, with the schema section removed. I'm trying to extract all of the "Events" nodes:

```
library(xml2)

test_xml <- as_xml_document(
'<Root>
  <xs:schema xmlns="address.com" xmlns:mstns="address.com" id="id">
  </xs:schema>
    <NewDataSet xmlns="address.com">
      <Events>
        <VAR1>3119496</VAR1>
        <VAR2>3119496</VAR2>
        <VAR3>text</VAR3>
      </Events>
      <Events>
        <VAR1>3119496</VAR1>
        <VAR2>3119496</VAR2>
        <VAR3>text</VAR3>
      </Events>
    </NewDataSet>
</Root>'
)
```

And here's a picture of my RStudio when I use `read_xml("file_path") %>% View()`:

[image]

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340237/convert-xml-to-a-data-frame) I would expect something like the following to work...

```
xml_df <- test_xml %>%
    xml_child(2) %>%
    xml_find_all("//Events") %>% 
    map_df(~ { xml_attrs(.x) %>% as.list() } )
```

...but it doesn't. My guess is that the problem is with my xpath in `xml_find_all`, but I'm not sure. Any help would be really appreciated!

EDIT: Given that the first answer did not work (before I added in the namespaces) I am guessing that the namespaces in the new example are causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this question in the future, the problem above was because of the namespaces in the xml.

Combining Allan's answer above with [the response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55727236/xml-find-all-function-from-xml2-package-r-does-not-find-relevant-nodes), I just needed to either use `xml_ns_strip()` or the code below to turn my xml into a dataframe.

```
xml_df <- test_xml %>%
  xml_find_all(xpath = "//d1:Events", xml_ns(.)) %>%
  as_list() %>%
  map_df(~ unlist(.))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```r
test_xml %>% 
  xml_find_all(xpath = "//Events") %>% 
  as_list() %>% 
  lapply(function(x) as.data.frame(t(unlist(x)))) %>% 
  {do.call(rbind, .)}

#>      VAR1    VAR2
#> 1 3119496 3119496
#> 2 3119496 3119496
```

Comment: Thanks - this does work for the sample data I provided, but doesn't work for my actual data. My reprex must have not captured my actual data well enough. I've edited my original post to hopefully correct that.